# Node-Red, launch cmd in function node with if statement

Tags: function, shell, if-statement, node-red

I want to know if it's possible to launch cmd (ex: sudo reboot) with function node using "if statement". By example i want to retrieve cpu temperature, when temperature is higher, I want to reboot PC.

Comment: yes, it's possible. I suggest using a switch node rather than a function node. Have a go and edit the question if you get stuck

Comment: The tag [tag:cmd] seems inappropriate as the operating systems assoiciated with it don't have sudo

Answer (score 0):

You will want a flow something like the following:

```
inject-+->exec(check temperature)->switch(>target)->exec(reboot)
```

An initial inject to start the flow when Node-RED starts and repeat periodically. Check the temperature, feed the output into a switch to check if the temperature is over your target. If it is, issue a reboot.

I've shown an exec to check the temperature but there may be other ways as well depending on your operating system. If using exec to get the temperature, you might also need a `change` node to process the output.